# crawl-delay: x --------- has someone here managed to understand how the math works there?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt

From prior research of reading different articles, I understand that a robots.txt crawl delay such as `crawl-delay: 1` allows a given search engine to *crawl x number of webpages per one second*, and than stop, until next time.

### My problem

It is unclear to me `from when` → `until when`, it stops (24 hours?).

It is further unclear to me what it does after I have read [the following statement here](https://yoast.com/ultimate-guide-robots-txt/):

> By setting a crawl delay of 10 seconds you’re only allowing these search engines to access 8,640 pages a day.

### My question

`crawl-delay: x`; has someone here managed to understand how the math works there?

Comment: And yes, I know that this feature **might** be good, generally, only to very large websites of millions of users or something similar.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128101/what-does-crawl-delay1-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crawl delay setting is the minimum number of seconds between page fetches allowed.  It is not the "number of webpages per one second" as you postulate.

For example, with a crawl delay of `10` a crawler should:

1. Crawl page A
2. Wait at least 10 seconds
3. Crawl page B

That would mean that crawler could crawl at most 6 pages per minute (sixty seconds divided by 10), 360 pages per hour, or 8,640 pages per day.  The smaller the crawl delay, the more crawling is allowed.

Many web crawlers don't support the `crawl-delay` directive.  For example Googlebot ignores it and instead backs off crawling if your site is slowing down (dynamic reactive crawl-delay).

As a webmaster, I never set the `crawl-delay`.   Not enough crawlers support it to make a difference in server load.   When it is set to a large value, it can hurt your SEO for search engines whose bots do follow it.

Comment: Hello again Stephen ; I am sorry to disturb you on this matter but please only tell me if `crawl-delay: 1` should bring crawling of up to 1 webpage per second, hence 30 webpages in a minute.

Comment: A crawled lay of one would allow crawling of it most 60 documents in one minute because there are 60 seconds in one minute.

Comment: If your server is super fast and serves pages instantaneously, the fastest a crawler could go is 60 pages per second.   It also isn't clear if the wait time is supposed to be between the start of a request to the start of the next, or whether the delay should be between the end a request and the start of the next.  Different crawlers may interpret it differently because the specific meaning is not codified in any spec as far as I know.

Comment: Crawlers are always free to crawl at a slower rate.   Crawlers are always free to go slower and wait longer that the specified delay if they want.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128101/what-does-crawl-delay1-mean

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>This answer is just an edited version of Stephen Ostermiller's
>   answer which I have accepted and suggest to up vote (as I myself did).
>   I publish it here because it is easier for me to read by means of web
>   accessibility.</sub>

The crawl delay setting is the minimum number of seconds between page fetches allowed.
So, it is not the "number of webpages per one second" as you have postulated.

For example, with a crawl delay of `10`, a crawler should:

1. Crawl page A
2. Wait at least 10 seconds
3. Crawl page B

That would mean that crawler could crawl at most 6 pages per minute (sixty seconds divided by 10), 360 pages per hour, or 8,640 pages per day.

The smaller the crawl delay, the more crawling is allowed.

### Side notes

- Many web crawlers don't support the `crawl-delay` directive.  For example Googlebot ignores it and instead backs off crawling if your site is slowing down (dynamic reactive crawl-delay).
- As a webmaster, I never set the `crawl-delay`.   Not enough crawlers support it to make a difference in server load.   When it is set to a large value, it can hurt your SEO for search engines whose bots do follow it.

### Update

> `Stephen later added in comments:`
>
> If your server is super fast and serves pages instantaneously, the
>   fastest a crawler could go is 60 pages per second.
>
> It also isn't clear if the wait time is supposed to be between the
>   start of a request to the start of the next, or whether the delay
>   should be between the end a request and the start of the next.
>
> Different crawlers may interpret it differently because the specific
>   meaning is not codified in any spec as far as I know.
>
> `I replied`:
>
> Stephen, I think these are very important issues --- if I understand
>   you correctly, one cannot know what will be the outcome of
>   crawl-delay: 1 (30 seconds, 60 seconds or something in between these
>   numbers) as it depends on application performance. Well, I do
>   webmastering since 2008 but I have never came across such data. I
>   think it is very important to be added in to your answer and I will
>   give bounty if this is the price for us having a good session about
>   this for all newcomers in the future.
>
> `Stephen replied:`
>
> Crawlers are always free to crawl at a slower rate. Crawlers are
>   always free to go slower and wait longer that the specified delay if
>   they want.
>
> `I currently add here:`
>
> My problem is that the `crawl-delay: 1` **30 seconds versus 60 seconds issue** is still not fully dealt with for others and for ourselves; I personally have read in several different documents and came out confused and I believe Stephen removed all my confusion besides in that particular issue